# Do the breakable wooden crates contain supplies?

Tags: black-mesa

Just getting started with Black Mesa. Before I go smashing all wooden crates I see with the crowbar, I would like to know: Do the wooden crates contain supplies?

Comment: Why would you ever consider **not** smashing all the crates?  Even if they had nothing inside of them, crates deserve smashing.

Comment: @Daniel "*... crates deserve smashing.*" Be careful of the crates marked 'Explosive', though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Steam version of Black Mesa, the small H.E.V. crates with the Black Mesa logo will always have supplies. The label on top will show what type of supplies are inside.

[image: Medkit supply crate]

Answer (score 6):

James Kane, one of the developers of Black Mesa Source [has been quoted](http://forums.blackmesasource.com/showpost.php?p=346096&postcount=13013) saying the following;

> We already have a crate which is unique to all others which gives supplies, but are very limited in locations. However, standard crates in all the variants may contain goodies, junk, or air. It is our decision to keep it as such for rewarding players who like to explore, examine, and break random crap.

[image: image of crates]

*A special undisclosed crate will give supplies but standard crates may contain either goodies, junk, or air (type regardless)*

<sup>[Black Mesa: Source Props & Textures](https://web.archive.org/web/20161111055205/http://wiki.blackmesasource.com:80/Props_&_Textures)</sup>

Comment: Good to know.  I had just assumed they all contained air.

Comment: @MBraedley - Same here, it wasn't til near the end that I realized they contained useful items instead of just junk.

Comment: Has anyone found out what or where that "*special undisclosed crate*" is?