# Can all crates contain supplies?

Tags: half-life

Should I break every crate I come across? Are there crate types that can **always contain supplies** and kinds that **never have anything usable inside**?

Comment: It seems like this is the case as designated supply crates were introduced in HL2, but I'm not certain.

Comment: [same question for Black Mesa remake](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84679/do-the-breakable-wooden-crates-contain-supplies)

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

In my experience, most boxes were only obstacles, scenery, or in the case of that one level, traps.

The taller ones with the tarp over it will drop gibs appearing as military surplus supplies (shovels, radios, packs, etc.), but you cannot use them.